# prolog facts and variables

Tags: prolog, puzzle

I was just wondering how I would make a fact such as

```
family(original, [dad/1, mom/2, child/5, granny/10]).
```

where `original` would be the name of the family, and the list is composed of titles and speeds.

how do I separate the number from the title (eg. `dad/1`), so I can do something like this:

```
time_needed(dad,1).
time_needed(mom,2).
time_needed(child,5).
time_needed(granny,10).
```

Answer (score 2):

What you wrote in your example is fine. You can make pairs with any delimiter that is declared as infix binary operator. That includes `/`, `+`, `,`, `-` etc... You can then pattern match pairs this way thanks to unification:

```
test :-
    family(X, [Title/Speed|_]),
    time_needed(Title, Speed).
```

Here I only pattern matched the first element but you can see the idea.

Though, note that usually `-` is used instead of `/` to delimit pairs. In particular, if you use SWI, the [`pairs`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.18%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/pairs.html%27%29%29) library uses a `Key-Value` syntax.

Comment: how would I use this for all the members in the list?

`test(?) :-
 family(_,[Title/Speed|Es]),
 person(Title,Speed),
        test(_,Es).`

Answer (score 1):

You need to assert elements of the list. Note that this way you lose the `original` key.

```
:- dynamic time_needed/2.
assert_family(Key) :-
  family(Key, List),
  assert_list(List).

assert_list([]).
assert_list([N/V|Es]) :-
  assertz(time_needed(N, V)),
  assert_list(Es).
```

and you call `assert_family(original).`

If your Prolog has forall/2 (or maplist/2 + library(lambda)) the code could be more compact:

```
:- dynamic time_needed/2.
assert_family(Key) :-
  family(Key, List),
  forall(member(N/V, List),
         assertz(time_needed(N, V))).
```

i.e. the recursive loop now it's 'inlined' in forall/2. But that library predicate hides behind syntactic simplicity some weird behaviour... Go with the simpler recursive loop.